# Setting Xcode's target to iPhone NOT iPad

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, simulator

I just upgraded to iPhone SDK 3.2 Beta 4. Since doing so, I have not been able to get the app to launch in the iPhone simulator - it keeps launching in the iPad simulator. I have tried option-clicking the drop-down menu in the top left-corner of Xcode and setting 'Active Executable' to iPhone simulator 3.1.3 but it keeps going back to iPad simulator instead.

What gives? I have no interest in my app running on the iPad and I don't want to test it in the 2X mode in the simulator.

Thanks,

Comment: Questions about pre-release Apple SDKs should be asked on the confidential Apple forums, not on public forums.

Comment: The question is fine, it is not discussing anything confidential.

Comment: Remember the first rule of apple-pre-release club is that no one talks about apple-pre-release club!

Comment: +1 for mentioning the option-click. Not totally obvious, I must say

Comment: In XCode 3.2.5 setting Simulator 4.2 is ignored in Debug mode but not in Release mode

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't really launch an iPhone app in 3.2.x - sometimes it will pop up - but basically right now it is only for iPad development.

Comment: Thanks - that was the problem. Changing the active SDK to 3.1.3 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 9):

Update for release version of Simulator.

First of all, the title of this question doesn't match the description: Xcode target isn't the same as the simulator hardware device.

If you are writing an app targeting 3.2, it can run on both iPad (using OS 3.2) and lower OS versions on the iPhone.  You do this by setting the Base SDK to iPhone Device 3.2, the Targeted Device Family to iPhone/iPad, and the iPhone OS Deployment Target to 3.1 (lower than 3.2).

The iPhone simulator has a menu option for Hardware->Device, which can be set to iPhone or iPad.  However, you can only run a 3.2 SDK target in iPad mode, and a Universal app that supports iPad can only use the 3.2 SDK to build.

You can of course set the simulator to iPhone mode and launch your app from Springboard, but that will lose the debugger connection.  Switching mode during installation of your app will cause it to crash.

So the short answer is still the same: you can't run a Universal iPad app in the iPhone mode simulator while debugging.

Answer (score 5):

Upper-left corner of the IDE find a dropdown list of Simulator versions - flipped to 3.2 - try to put it back to 3.1.3

and relaunch your app.

Answer (score 3):

This was driving me nuts too, but the answer is right here:

http://quatermain.tumblr.com/post/517122761/running-universal-ipad-iphone-apps-in-the-simulator

In short, tell Xcode to *Build* for the 3.2 SDK, then switch the build menu to the 3.1 SDK and tell Xcode to *Run* the app. Presto, the app starts in the iPhone simulator!

Answer (score 3):

From Apple's documentation: "iPhone OS 3.2 does not support iPhone and iPod touch devices. It runs only on iPad." There's no way to target 3.2 for iPhone, so there's no Simulator. Ergo, you'll have to wait for iOS 4. Fortunately, that's only 4 days away now... of course it won't support the first generation of iPhone devices, but for all other iPhone users it's a free upgrade. Not sure about iPod Touches.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change your target platform in your Project Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the target platform and device makes no difference.  It always launches the iPad simulator.

If you switch the simulator to iPhone mode, the app just disappears.

This dev environment is a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can change the hardware setting in the simulator. Hardware->Device

Comment: This doesn't work if you launch your app in 3.2.  The fix is to launch in 3.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project 
Set Active Executable
There are 2 options: Ipad Simulator 3.2 or Iphone Simulator 4.0.
If you choose the Iphone simulator, then it will launch Iphone simulator.
If you choose the Ipad simulator, then it will launch Ipad simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem myself.

First, install new version of xCode, which is xCode 4.

Then set project scheme to iphone simulator and run app in xCode several times.

And re-install xCode 3 and the problem will be gone away!