# Why does Xcode launch the iPhone simulator when the iPad simulator is selected?

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

When I open an existing iPad project in Xcode and "Build and Run" it, it launches the iPhone simulator when I have the iPad Simulator set as the active executable?  Inside the iPhone simulator is a shrunken version of the iPad.  What is going on?  How do I get it to run the iPad simulator?

*Note: When the iPhone Simulator is running, I double checked the Hardware->Device setting and it's set to iPad.  This is what I want, of course, but I don't want it to run the iPhone simulator.  I seem to recall it used to run an iPad simulator.  Is there such a thing or am I tripping and there is only an iPhone simulator that can run iPad apps?*

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413948/setting-xcodes-target-to-iphone-not-ipad

Comment: nope, that's a similar, but different problem and the solutions don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone simulator and the iPad simulator are the same application. If you're just concerned about the size of the iPad, go to Window -> Scale and choose "100%".

Comment: Thanks so much, that's what I was missing.

Comment: Does anyone know why both 100% and 50% menu options is disabled in my iPhone Simulator? :(

Comment: You can run the app on iPad simulator as well, go to Product --> Destination --> and select iPad/iPad Retina or whichever device you want, then run your application again it will get launched in the simulator selected by you (you can also choose your connected device there if you have one). - this is for xCode 5.0.2

Answer (score 1):

In the top left hand corner of xcode, next to the stop button, you will see your scheme. Click the iPad Simulator button and change it to iPhone.

[image: Scheme Toolbar]