# XCode Interface Builder iPad/iPhone

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

Just a silly question that just cant figure out. Ive been working on iPad apps for a while but now Im back on an iphone project. 
I created an iphone 4.0 sdk based project but when i double tap on a xib file, IB comes with iPad layout and i cant figure out how to switch it back to iphone layout.

Anyone?

Comment: whats the active executable you are building for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the project, be sure to select Product = iPhone in the "New Project" window.

Also, if you already have the iPad views, you can transform them to iPod/iPhone views through File->Create iPod/iPhone Version using autosizing masks

Comment: Althrough i select product= iphone, keeps creating new xibs with ipad layout. I used autosizing masks but the ipad version keeps there and doesnt sound as an elegant solution, despite that it works anyway.TY!

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413948/setting-xcodes-target-to-iphone-not-ipad

Answer (score 0):

Partially solved,solution sucks. i created a view based project and there IB shows xib with iphone layout. Couldnt find a solution yet when creating a window based project.